# GROUP_CONCAT on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have two tables, with independent ids (can't be connected via joins), I want to query and get a GROUP_CONCAT of both columns.

Example: table "a" has ids: **1, 2, 3**. table "b" has the ids: **10, 11**.

End result should be: **1, 2, 3, 10, 11**

I have tried a few queries:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT(a.id), GROUP_CONCAT(b.id)) AS combined FROM a, b

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.id, b.id) AS combined FROM a, b
```

These queries are returning me duplicate results though 8as in, all results from a twice and all results from b twice as well)

Comment: Could using `UNION` help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `union all`:

```
select group_concat(ab.id) as ids
from ((select id from a
      ) union all
      (select id from b
      )
     ) ab;
```

Your queries are doing cross join's between the tables, so data after the cross join is:

```
a.id        b.id
 1           10
 1           11
 2           10
 2           11
 3           10
 3           11
```

After the `union all`, the data is:

```
ab.id
  1
  2
  3
 10
 11
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT [])`

will help

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

If you want duplicates, use `union all`. If you don't want duplicates, use `union`.
In either case, the query you need is as follows:

```
select group_concat(id) from
 (select id from a
  union
  select id from b) as ids;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will generate that you want.
You can play with the table_position dynamic column for deciding which table goes first.

```
 Select group_concat(id order by table_position) from 
   (
      select id, 1 as table_position from a
      union all
      select id, 2 as table_position from b
    )
```